# A question related to the boundedness of an inverse operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm currently in the process of constructing a proof for the statement below:

> If an operator $A$ on $\mathcal{H}$ (Hilbert space) is closed, bounded away from zero, and has a dense range in $\mathcal{H}$, then $A$ has a bounded inverse.

**Remarks:** $(1)$ An operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is a linear map $T:\mathcal{D}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, where $\mathcal{D}(A)$ is a *dense* subspace of $\mathcal{H}$, and $(2)$ An operator $A$ is *bounded away from zero* if there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $\|Av\| \geq c\|v\|$, for all, $v \in \mathcal{D}(A)$.

I've managed to prove the following claim (which is provided as a hint to prove the main statement):

> If an operator $A$ is closed and bounded away from zero, then $A$ is injective and *range$(A)$* is closed.

I'm allowed to make use of the following result (known as the **Inverse Mapping Theorem**):

> An operator $A$ has a bounded inverse iff it is closed and bijective.

**My question is:** if the *range$(A)$* is both closed and dense in $\mathcal{H}$, does that imply that $A$ is bijective?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dense closed subsets coincide with the whole space, this implies that $A$ is onto. Since $A$ is also bounded away from $0$, $A$ is also injective.